# Temperature distribution simulation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am currently working on a storage tank heated with an internal hot water coil.I need to know how does the temperature distribution look like in the tank.

I have tried the steady state model in Matlab, but I Don't find it very precise ( I can only enter thermal conductivities of the product and the tank material + Boundary conditions ) In my opinion, this makes the distribution too generic and not specific to my case. I also tried the transient model and but there are some errors while running the code.

Here's the code I used for the transient model ( I am new to Matlab, so please excuse any code errors)

```
model = createpde('thermal','transient');
geo = multicylinder([3.4,3.5],7.1)
model.Geometry= geo;
pdegplot(model,'FaceLabels',"on")
generateMesh(model);
pdemesh(model)


 thermalProperties(model,"Cell",2,"ThermalConductivity",0.1,"MassDensity",576,"SpecificHeat",0.5)
 thermalProperties(model,"Cell",1,"MassDensity",932,"SpecificHeat",2.28,"ThermalConductivity",0.12)
 thermalIC(model,0)
 tlist=0:.1:5

Thermalresults = solve(model,tlist);
u= Thermalresults.Temperature
pdeplot3D(model,'ColorMapData', u)
```